# Can you count duplicate rows, left join to the appropriate row and then group all within 1 table?

Tags: mysql

I seriously don't know if its possible but Can you count duplicate rows, left join to the appropriate row and then group all within 1 table?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want?  sample data, table structure, etc. What do you mean _left join to the appropriate row_?

Comment: You can self join (join a table to itself).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(name)
      FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
      WHERE t1.name = t2.name;

This will give you the count of rows that the name in table1 is the same as in table2.  I am assuming that is what you mean by duplicates.  A left outer is not needed as it will show records from the left (table1) that do not have a match on the right (table2).  If they do not have a match they are n